# Error while Installing EJBCA 6

Tags: java, ant, jboss7.x, ejbca

I am installing EJBCA 6 on my linux machine using given ant

I have successfully deployed it in jboss-as-7 server using following command

```
ant deploy
```

but when i install ejbca using `ant install`  command it gives folloing error

```
ejbca:initCA:
     [echo] Initializing CA with 'myCompnyCA1' 'CN=myCompnyCA1,O=myCompny,C=US' 'soft' <ca.tokenpassword hidden> '2048' 'RSA' '3650' 'null' 'SHA1WithRSA'   -superadmincn 'SuperAdmin'...
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.

ejbca:adminweb:
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.
     [echo] batch tomcat
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.

ejbca:batchsuperadmin:
     [echo] batch superadmin
     [java] CLI authentication failed. The user 'ejbca' with the given password does not exist.

BUILD FAILED
/home/indra/EJBCA_6_and_jobss_as_7/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/build.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/indra/EJBCA_6_and_jobss_as_7/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/build.xml:66: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/indra/EJBCA_6_and_jobss_as_7/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/bin/cli.xml:96: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/indra/EJBCA_6_and_jobss_as_7/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/bin/cli.xml:137: Batch generation failed!
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

I just deleted the old ejbca data base and re-create with same credentials..

**The problem was**: - in past i was using ejbca 4.. for that i was created data base named ejbca and i was trying to use same database for ejbca 6 which was giving error, finally deletion and creation of data base solved my problem

Comment: how did you cleaned up the old ejcba database? were you using h2 or mysql or what db?

Comment: I am using mysql.. i just Emptied the whole database using SQLyog